# Install Code::Blocks 12.11 on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, deb, code-blocks

Just downloaded the Code::Blocks .bz2 file, extracted it and have a bunch of files which I don't know what to do with.

A friend once showed me how to install it using the command line, but I can't remember how to do it. I think I used a package manager or something from the command line? They are all .deb files.

The solution is NOT to open them all using the Software Center -- installing this way destroys the OS.

Comment: You said "Installing this way destroys the OS". Any reason for that?

Comment: Yes, as I remember, unless you know the specific order in which to install them, then all hell breaks loose, and it 'just wont work anymore'. (As in you can get to the desktop after restart, but you wont be able to install anything ever again until you remove all the packages you tried to install.)

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I'm trying to install CB on Ubuntu 12.10 right now. I did it from Software Center, and got 10.05. What's the best way to install 12.11?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the problem I had. Google for code::blocks, go to their page and download the binary release. (You want the stable one, I would assume.)

You should extract the downloaded archive, and find you have a bunch of .deb files. Launch a terminal, cd to this directory, and type `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and this will install everything without messing up the os.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Which will automate the process.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 I downloaded Code::Blocks 13.12 (Debian Stable x86_64), extracted the bzip and tried using this command.  Failed to install and left synaptic with a handful of broken packages that had to be cleared out.  No silver bullet here, unfortunately.

Comment: @MattH. That's a different version, I'm guessing some changes were made which broke this method. Could you ask a question and tag me in a comment so I can find out the solution to doing this for version 13.12?